# SSH, SVN and firewalls

Tags: networking, ssh, firewall, svn, ssh-tunnel

I have a typical set up where by my SVN server is on a machine behind the firewall and I have a gateway machine which I can SSH into. When outside the network if I want to checkout the repository I would use a tunnel.

```
ssh user@gateway_machine.domain.co.uk 3690:svn_machine:3690 -fN
```

Then checkout:

```
svn co svn://localhost/branch/to/source
```

The problem is what to do if I already checked out a branch because then the `SVN URL` is:

```
svn://svn_machine.domain.co.uk/branch/to/source
```

Making the tunnel useless.

What can be done to make my system aware that connections to `svn_machine` need to go through `gateway_machine` when outside the network?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting up a proxy in the subversion servers file: ( ~/.subversion/servers in Linux)

```
[global]
http-proxy-exceptions = *.domain.co.uk
http-proxy-host = gateway_machine.domain.co.uk
http-proxy-port = 3690
http-proxy-username = user
http-proxy-password = pass
http-compression = no
```

Comment: Put this in `~/.subversion/servers` file on the local machine correct?

Comment: Yep, whichever machine holds your local SVN

Comment: This doesn't do trick, I might be missing something? This still gives `svn: E670002: Unknown hostname 'svn_machine.domain.co.uk'`

Comment: If that doesn't work, there is an alternative route you could try here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/82530/svn-over-http-proxy